# Spring-Data-Neo4J :: How do I save an array or enums in a relationship?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my `@RelationshipEntity` below, you can see I have a `Set<Right> rights` (set of rights). `Right` is an `Emum`. Neo4J would only allow me to save a set of `String`'s so I nade a custom converter.

```
@RelationshipEntity (type="LOGIN")
public class Login {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @StartNode
    Person person;

    @EndNode
    Organisation organisation;

    @Property
    String role;

    @Property
    @Convert(RightConverter.class)
    Set<Right> rights = new HashSet<Right>();

    public Login() {
        // Empty Constructor
    }

    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

It all made sense to me, but when I run the application, I get an error fro my `RightConverter` class.

```
public class RightConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<Right>, Set<String>> {
    public Set<String> toGraphProperty(Set<Right>  rights) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (Right right : rights) {
            result.add(right.name());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Set<Right> toEntityAttribute(Set<String> rights) {
        Set<Right> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (String right : rights) {
            result.add(Right.valueOf(right));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It works for save, but not for load:

```
nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of com.noxgroup.nitro.domain.Person
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
at com.noxgroup.nitro.domain.converters.RightConverter.toEntityAttribute(RightConverter.java:9) ~[main/:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest snapshot of SDN 4 (i.e. post the M1 release), then there is no need to write a converter for collections or arrays of enums. The default enum converter will convert the Set of enums into a String array for you.

However, if you're using an earlier build(M1) then this support did not exist so you do need to write a converter. In that case, `RightConverter` just has to change to convert to an array of Strings which is what Neo4j will finally use, not a collection. This works:

```
public class RightConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<Right>, String[]> {
    public String[] toGraphProperty(Set<Right>  rights) {
        String[] result = new String[rights.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Right right : rights) {
            result[i++] = right.name();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Set<Right> toEntityAttribute(String[] rights) {
        Set<Right> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (String right : rights) {
            result.add(Right.valueOf(right));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have (I think) the latest snapshot build (how do I check), but it's still not working for me.

Comment: Any idea when RC1 will be out?

Comment: If you have org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT then you're using the snapshot. RC1- the best I can say at the moment is "soon"

Comment: Is the default converter not working or your own converter? If you've switched to the default and you're loading an entity persisted earlier, please make sure that the Rights are indeed stored as an array of Strings on the node.

Comment: My converter works 100's. The default converter doesn't. I'm starting from scratch every run (clearing the database). Error is: nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?I'm okay using my converter for now though. Just wondering why the default converter isn't working.

Comment: Unless your data is off, it should work, I've tested it. If you can edit your post with a small test case that fails, that would be great